# cut off beginning of file without "read"ing the rest

Tags: tcl

I have a script that that writes a small amount of encrypted information to a file, and then appends another file using cat:

`exec cat $in.header $in.db > $in.dbx`

The `$in.header` file is always the same size. Is there a way to extract `$in.db` from `$in.dbx` without "read"ing the rest of the file? This is what it looks like now:

```
set outfile [open $out.db wb]
while {![eof $infile]} {
    set input [read $infile 4096]
    puts -nonewline $outfile $input
}
```

It works, but I have to think that there's a better way, some of the files can be quite large.

Comment: You might like the `fcopy`/`chan copy` command. It replaces that loop, using the right buffer size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't chop off the beginning of a file without copying it; no modern operating system offers you the ability to do that. You can sometimes tell code to start looking in a file from a particular position onwards, but only sometimes.

You can use `seek` (aka `chan seek`) to move around in an open file, and if you are copying data out then consider using `fcopy`; it's extremely fast, especially when doing a binary-to-binary copy.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to overwrite part of an existing file $in.dbx with new encrypted information? If so, you may use "seek" command to move write-position of the file. For example, at 4096-byte offset:

```
set chn1 [open $in.dbx r+]
fconfigure $chn1 -translation binary
seek $chn1 4096 start
puts -nonewline $chn1 $encrypted_info
close $chn1
```

Comment: The first 4116 bytes of .dbx contain file hash and other information, and I open that file and read those bytes and they are assigned a variable for later parsing. Everything after the 4116th byte is the actual .db file, and I would like to separate that from the first 4116 bytes without having to "read" from .dbx and "puts" to .db everything after those first 4116.